# Not able to switch cards in cardlayout in single jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, cardlayout

Sorry if its an obvious question.I have been trying to switch panels in the same window using cardlayout.But when i run my application nothing happens.
    System.out.println(mntmBookingStatus);
the above statement does get printed on console.but not able to make out why cards arent switching when i click on menuitem "booking status" and "invoice entry".

```
public class StartDemo {
private JFrame frame;
private JPanel cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                StartDemo window = new StartDemo();
                window.initialize();
                window.frame.pack();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 772, 700);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //frame.setVisible(true);
    // main menu
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    // mainmenuoption-1
    mnNewMenu = new JMenu("Entries");
    menuBar.add(mnNewMenu);

    // option-1 items
    mntmBookingStatus = new JMenuItem("Booking Status");
    mnNewMenu.add(mntmBookingStatus);
    mntmBookingStatus.addActionListener(new MenuListenerAdapter());

mntmInvoiceEntry = new JMenuItem("Invoice Entry");
mnNewMenu.add(mntmInvoiceEntry);
mntmInvoiceEntry.addActionListener(new MenuListenerAdapter());
StartDemo demo = new StartDemo();
    demo.addComponentToPane(frame.getContentPane());

}

public void addComponentToPane(Container pane) {
JPanel booking_status = new JPanel();
    JPanel invoice_entry = new JPanel();
    JPanel customer_ledger = new JPanel();
    JPanel create_user = new JPanel();

    try {

        JPanelWithBackground panelWithBackground = new       JPanelWithBackground(
                "D:\\Kepler Workspace\\WEDemo\\images\\abc.jpg");
        cards.add(panelWithBackground, "name_282751308799");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 //the layout code for all the panels is written here.
//its to big to post here

cards.add(booking_status, BOOKINGPANEL);
    cards.add(invoice_entry, INVOICEPANEL);
    cards.add(customer_ledger, CUSTOMERLEDGER);
    cards.add(create_user, CREATEUSER);

    pane.add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}

public class MenuListenerAdapter implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        CardLayout c = (CardLayout) (cards.getLayout());

        if (e.getSource() == mntmBookingStatus) {
            c.show(cards, BOOKINGPANEL);
            System.out.println(mntmBookingStatus);

        } else if (e.getSource() == mntmInvoiceEntry) {
            c.show(cards, INVOICEPANEL);
            System.out.println(mntmInvoiceEntry);

        }

    }
```

This is my JPanelWithBackground class

```
public class JPanelWithBackground extends JPanel {

private Image backgroungImage;
private Image scaledBackgroundImage;


  // Some code to initialize the background image.
  // Here, we use the constructor to load the image. This
  // can vary depending on the use case of the panel.

public JPanelWithBackground(String fileName) throws IOException {
    backgroungImage = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));
}


public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    // Draw the backgroung image
    g.drawImage(backgroungImage, 0, 0,getWidth(),getHeight(),null);
}
```

Comment: Why do so many newbs feel like it's necessary to set the frame visible before adding any components. Doesn't make sense to me how such logic could be overlooked :/

Comment: Back on topic. Please post a compilable runnable example. From first glance, I don't see much wrong with the code above.

Comment: @peeskillet -- have edited my post.. Please check..

Comment: Why `frame.setBounds()`? Why not a simple call like `frame.setLocationByPlatform(true) or frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null)` is enough? Moreover, use [Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), if the `JMenuItem` as well as the `JButton` are doing the same thingy, to avoid redundant code snippets.

Comment: @nIcEcOw -  thanx for your suggestions.. i did modified my code with setLocationRelativeto(null).. and also i am not using buttons to perform similar menu actions.. so havent used Actions.. though the information was helpful.. would use it in future if the scenario suits.. :)

Comment: @user3061692 : You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-) Do have a look at this post, regarding how to [Best position Swing GUIs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7143287/1057230), for making a choice between which of the two methods should be selected :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's these two lines right here

```
 StartDemo demo = new StartDemo();
 demo.addComponentToPane(frame.getContentPane());
```

Since your `initialize()` method isn't `static` I think it's safe to assume that you instantiate youe `StartDemo` *again* in the `main` method. In that case, the above code *truly is* your problem and would totally explain why it doesn't work. Just do this

```
 //StartDemo demo = new StartDemo();          <-- get rid of this.
 addComponentToPane(frame.getContentPane());
```

Tested with code additions only to get it running. Also please not my comments above. `setVisible(true)` generally is the *last* thing you should do *after* adding all components.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class StartDemo {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu mnNewMenu;
    JMenuItem mntmBookingStatus;
    JMenuItem mntmInvoiceEntry;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new StartDemo().initialize();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 772, 700);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // main menu
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        // mainmenuoption-1
        mnNewMenu = new JMenu("Entries");
        menuBar.add(mnNewMenu);

        // option-1 items
        mntmBookingStatus = new JMenuItem("Booking Status");
        mnNewMenu.add(mntmBookingStatus);
        mntmBookingStatus.addActionListener(new MenuListenerAdapter());

        //StartDemo demo = new StartDemo();
        addComponentToPane(frame.getContentPane()); mntmInvoiceEntry = new JMenuItem("Invoice Entry");
        mnNewMenu.add(mntmInvoiceEntry);
        mntmInvoiceEntry.addActionListener(new MenuListenerAdapter());

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void addComponentToPane(Container pane) {
        JPanel booking_status = new JPanel();
        JPanel invoice_entry = new JPanel();
        //JPanel customer_ledger = new JPanel();
        //JPanel create_user = new JPanel();

        try {

            JPanelWithBackground panelWithBackground = new JPanelWithBackground(
                    "/resources/stackoverflow5.png");
            cards.add(panelWithBackground, "name_282751308799");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        cards.add(booking_status, "booking");
        cards.add(invoice_entry, "invoice");
        //cards.add(customer_ledger, CUSTOMERLEDGER);
        //cards.add(create_user, CREATEUSER);

        pane.add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }


    class JPanelWithBackground extends JPanel {
        Image img; 
        public JPanelWithBackground(String path) throws IOException {
            img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path));
        }

        @Override 
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 300);
        }
    }

    public class MenuListenerAdapter implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            CardLayout c = (CardLayout) (cards.getLayout());

            if (e.getSource() == mntmBookingStatus) {
                c.show(cards,"booking");
                System.out.println(mntmBookingStatus);

            } else if (e.getSource() == mntmInvoiceEntry) {
                c.show(cards, "invoice");
                System.out.println(mntmInvoiceEntry);

            }

        }
    }
}
```